# DocumentDB - query result order

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure DocumentDB to store information about users. These documents contain a property called *date_created*. I'd like to send a query to documentDB to retrieve ALL users stored within this collection. I also want the result to be ordered from newest to oldest.

I currently implemented a stored procedure in DocumentDB that goes through the collection and sorts the results based on the date property. However, I have 2 questions:

1. When returning multiple documents for a query, what is the default ordering used by DocumentDB?
2. I understand that ordering control is not yet supported by DocumentDB, but if I use a store procedure to order the results, am I executing a full collection scan, or is the database at least leveraging the index of the property I am sorting for? For information, the store procedure I am using is this one (slightly modified from the Azure samples provided by the product team):

   ```
   function orderBy(filterQuery, orderByFieldName, continuationToken) { 
   // HTTP error codes sent to our callback funciton by DocDB server. 
   var ErrorCode = { 
       REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE: 413, 
   }
   var collection = getContext().getCollection(); 
   var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink(); 
   var result = new Array(); 

   tryQuery({}); 

   function tryQuery(options) { 
       var isAccepted = (filterQuery && filterQuery.length) ? 
           collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, filterQuery, options, callback) : 
           collection.readDocuments(collectionLink, options, callback) 

       if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("Source dataset is too large to complete the operation."); 
   } 

   /** 
   * queryDocuments callback. 
   * @param {Error} err - Error object in case of error/exception. 
   * @param {Array} queryFeed - array containing results of the query. 
   * @param {ResponseOptions} responseOptions. 
   */ 
   function callback(err, queryFeed, responseOptions) { 
       if (err) { 
           throw err; 
       } 

       // Iterate over document feed and store documents into the result array. 
       queryFeed.forEach(function (element, index, array) { 
           result[result.length] = element; 
       }); 

       if (responseOptions.continuation) { 
           // If there is continuation, call query again providing continuation token. 
           tryQuery({ continuation: responseOptions.continuation }); 
       } else { 
           // We are done with querying/got all results. Sort the results and return from the script. 
           result.sort(compare); 

           fillResponse(); 
       } 
   } 

   // Compare two objects(documents) using field specified by the orderByFieldName parameter. 
   // Return 0 if equal, -1 if less, 1 if greater. 
   function compare(x, y) { 
       if (x[orderByFieldName] == y[orderByFieldName]) return 0; 
       else if (x[orderByFieldName] < y[orderByFieldName]) return 1; 
       return -1; 
   } 

   // This is called in the very end on an already sorted array. 
   // Sort the results and set the response body. 
   function fillResponse() {
       var page_size = 20;
       // Main script is called with continuationToken which is the index of 1st item to start result batch from. 
       // Slice the result array and discard the beginning. From now on use the 'continuationResult' var. 
       var continuationResult = result; 
       if (continuationToken) continuationResult = result.slice(continuationToken); 
       else continuationToken = 0;

       if (page_size > continuationResult.length ) {
           page_size = continuationResult.length;
       }

       // Get/initialize the response. 
       var response = getContext().getResponse(); 
       response.setBody(null); 

       // Take care of response body getting too large: 
       // Set Response iterating by one element. When we fail due to MAX response size, return to the client requesting continuation. 
       var i = 0;
       var final_result = [];
       for (; i < page_size; ++i) { 
           try { 
               // Note: setBody is very expensive vs appendBody, use appendBody with simple approximation JSON.stringify(element).
               final_result.push(continuationResult[i]);                   
           } catch (ex) { 
               if (!ex.number == ErrorCode.REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE) throw ex; 
               break; 
           } 
       } 

       /* Now next batch to return to client has i elements. 
       // Slice the continuationResult if needed and discard the end. */
       var partialResult = continuationResult; 
       var newContinuation = null; 
       if (i < continuationResult.length) { 
           partialResult = continuationResult.slice(0, i); 
       }

       // Finally, set response body.          
       response.setBody({ result: final_result, continuation: i }); 
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: can your answer work for order by the sub property ex : orderby Name.FirstName where name has three properties, firstName, LastName and MiddleName?

Comment: @satishkumarV I think it should, look at the function written in my answer above: 'function compare(x, y) { 
    if (x[orderByFieldName] == y[orderByFieldName]) return 0; 
    else if (x[orderByFieldName] < y[orderByFieldName]) return 1; 
    return -1; 
} '
As long as you can access those subfields on "x" and "y", then the compare function will take care of sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: As of July, 2015 - DocumentDB supports ORDER BY in queries**

At the moment, you'll need to sort the collection on the client or stored procedures (although I'd I'd recommend doing so on the client since stored procedures have bounded execution).

To answer your questions:

1) I don't believe there is a guaranteed default ordering

2) The Stored Procedure would result in a collection scan and then sort it.

You can help push for "Order By" by voicing your opinion on the Azure Feedback Forums at:
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6334829--order-by-in-queries

Comment: ^^ BTW, this feature is now implemented in DocumentDB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn782250.aspx